# Get list of recent activity and time of that activity

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

I was wondering if there was anyway to view the recent activity on my MacBook.  I accidentally left it unlocked for an hour in an environment that I do not trust and want to see if anybody did anything while I was away. I am using a 2015 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're looking for... you'll see any commands that required sudo in the system.log file. But there isn't a generic 'log activity' type of service. With Apple Remote Desktop you could enable some additional logging to see which users log in, log out, and what apps they use.

Comment: I was concerned about folders/ files being opened or copied to a flash drive, I wanted to know if any of my windows had been manipulated in anyway, and  I was hoping there would be some kind of corresponding time stamp.  Thank you for your reply, it looks like the info I desire is not available.